# Conditional formatting Google sheets, if formula not used

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to highlight cells which have been manually entered by using the `formulatext()` function. However, at the moment this is highlighting all the cells that have a different outcome (from if statements) to the first cell. Can this be changed?

(If curious my exact formula at the moment is `=formulatext(E4)<>if(B4= "","",if(left(CN4,1)<>"-",if(or(D4="A",D4="B"),if(AF4<>"","DONE",CN4),if(AF4<>"","DONE",CN4)),if(or(D4="A",D4="B"),if(AF4<>"","DONE","over 48h"),if(AF4<>"","DONE","over 36h"))))`, the formula inside is working so no need to change it)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kOJf07eoe_8tYR9a2h1iv2OIBt77xprHiGER3InGg-g/edit?usp=sharing
I hope that link works.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example

Comment: @player0 I added a link if that helps

Comment: the sheet is private, pls share it